# Drupal2Wordpress trouble

Tags: mysql, wordpress, drupal

I'm using [Drupal2Wordpress plugin](https://github.com/jpSimkins/Drupal2WordPress-Plugin) to transfer my content from Drupal to WP, but I receive this error while trying to begin the process:
Failed to connect to the Drupal database.

Here is the log of the MySQL:

```
150426 14:31:11    18 Connect   root@localhost on   
18 Query    SET NAMES utf8  
18 Query    SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode  
18 Init DB  okna  
18 Query    SELECT option_name, option_value FROM wp_options WHERE autoload = 'yes'  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'theme_mods_twentyfifteen' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'current_theme' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'mods_Twenty Fifteen' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT * FROM wp_users WHERE user_login = 'admin'  
18 Query    SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE user_id IN (1) ORDER BY umeta_id ASC  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_pages' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_calendar' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_tag_cloud' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'widget_nav_menu' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'theme_switched' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'db_upgraded' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'dismissed_update_core' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT comment_approved, COUNT( * ) AS num_comments FROM wp_comments  GROUP BY comment_approved  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'auto_core_update_failed' LIMIT 1  
18 Query    SELECT autoload FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules'  
18 Query    SELECT option_value FROM wp_options WHERE option_name = 'rewrite_rules' LIMIT 1  
18 Quit
```

Do you guys have any ideas what to do? Or is my database config the problem?

Comment: Did you put in the correct settings for your Drupal Database on the Drupal DB Settings screen?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used this wp plugin, and i am assuming that this plugin needs the database login credentials of drupal and you have entered **localhost** as the db host of drupal. If this is the case then looks like db host is causing the problem. When you are in your drupal and you define host as localhost. That means that the database is installed on the same server where drupal is hosted, so it just searches for the database name in the server.

But now your database is not on the same localhost, you will have to use the remote host name, so that other applications can access this database. Not many hosts offer remote connections. First thing would be to ask your host about the remote connection, if they dont allow it then you cant do it directly.

**Here is a quick way around that i can think of:** Just dump the drupal database and create a new database from the dump in the wordpress hosting environment. Now when you refer localhost, it will be able to find the database. You dont need to transfer the whole drupal to this environment, simply migrating the database should do it.

**Note:** you might also have to assign new users to the database as the existing users wont be available in the wordpress environment.

**EDIT:** Check if you can connect to the database from wordpress. Create a connect.php file in the root of wordpress (where config.php is placed) and add this code.

```
<?php
$username = "your_name";
$password = "your_password";
$hostname = "localhost"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br>";
?>
```

**Replace with your credentials, unless you are able to connect to the database you wont be able to use the plugin.**

Comment: Well, thank you for your response, but they seem to be in the same place: http://i.imgur.com/hmEbH6q.png

Comment: Hey. I successfully connected to both "okna" and "old_okna" databases.

Comment: So were you able to use the plugin with the db details?

Comment: The plugin doesn't work while I can connect to the database. Probably I should try using an older version of Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was **the script not supporting connections with empty password.**
What a shame!